# getting error :TypeError: google.maps.Geocoder is not a constructor with Magento

Tags: javascript, magento, geocoding

I had working code when I used script in adminhtml From.php. But When I separated code and place in js file. I am getting below Error.

```
   TypeError: google.maps.Geocoder is not a constructor
   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

My code in js file is :

```
function loadjsfile(){
    alert("func called");
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false";
    document.head.appendChild(script);}
function getlatlong(){ 
//loadjsfile();
var address = document.getElementById("zipcode").value;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode( { "address": address}, function(results, status) {
var location = results[0].geometry.location;
foundLat = location.lat();
foundLng = location.lng();
//alert(location.lat() + "<br>" + location.lng());
document.getElementById("longitude").value= foundLng;
document.getElementById("latitude").value= foundLat;
});}

window.onload = loadjsfile;
```

Js file is loaded in `head` tag. Still getting error.

Please provide me sugesstion if u feel..
Thanks.